# Accessing Rails helpers from a presenter/module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, mvp

There are many questions about accessing Rails helpers from a model, all of which rightfully state that the answer is not to do that.  This is not that question.

I have some fairly complex controller and view code that I want to abstract into a presenter class.  But that class isn't a descendant of ApplicationController.  How can I get access to, say, devise's current_user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there's no "official right" way to do this at the moment.  Two possibilities:

1. It's hacky, but you can store the current controller in ApplicationController, and reference it in your presenters to get at the helpers:

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     prepend_before_filter { @@current_controller = self }
   end

   class YourPresenter
     def current_user
       ApplicationController.current_controller.current_user
     end
   end
   ```

   1. Jeff Casimir is working on a great Decorator/Presenter gem called *draper* that encapsulates the whole idea:

https://github.com/jcasimir/draper

Comment: Is this still the way to go in 2015?